# Does my HP Z820 workstation support WIndows 10 version 1809 feature update?

Tags: windows-10

The following link shows HP products tested with Windows 10:
https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05195282

Under 1809 version, for Z820 workstation, it says "EOS version 1803".
Can anyone please tell me what this means? If that is "End of Support/Service", does that mean I cannot use the Windows 10 version 1809 on my workstation?

Also, if that is the case and I install a previous version, e.g. 1803, will I be able to use it indefinitely, without Windows asking for an update?

I know one can postpone the feature update for a year, but after that, what does one needs to do?

Any help/suggestions would be highly appreciated ! Thanks in advance !

Comment: If your machine supports 1803 then it supports all current versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

EOS basically means End of Support. So, basically, HP has stopped recommending drivers and speculations for that system. This means that you will likely have to depend on vendor provided drivers, instead of HP drivers. 
From the link provided by OP:

> Once manufacturing a specific product has ended, HP will continue to test each newly introduced Windows 10 semi-annual channel for a period of three (3) years. During this time, the device may receive either a support rating of “web support” or “compatible driver support”.

Also, from the same URL:

> Tested - Not Supported
>   System Compatibility and Integration Testing (SCIT): HP will perform manual installation of drivers directly provided by vendors.

So basically, your model went out of support since version 1803.

As for whether you can update to version 1809, is totally dependent on you. Windows 10 is based on a WaaS (Windows as a Service) model, meaning, once purchased, you will get Windows (software) support (and updates) for lifetime. As for the driver support, you have to experiment yourself and depend on the specific hardware vendors, though it is not really common to have issues there.

This also means that you can't postpone your update too long. In fact, it is strongly recommended to update, since, while some updates are known to break things, updating also allows your system to be secure against various vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Although a particular PC has not yet been *tested* for compatibility with a new version of an OS, this does not mean it wouldn't work well with it (nor that it would). Since it is difficult to turn off Windows updates without disconnecting the PC from the internet, it might be worthwhile to test the update yourself, **if you have a clear path to restoring v. 1803 if things go bad.**

1. Make a complete disk image on external media. There are many excellent free applications to do so, such as [Macrium Reflect](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) and [DriveImage XML](https://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm). Verify the image before you trust it.
2. Apply the latest update... often, the easiest and quickest way is from an [ISO image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10).
3. Test all your software operation under the new OS.

   a. If everything is OK, well and good, enable normal updates.

   b. If not, restore your backup image and [disable MS updates](https://www.easeus.com/todo-backup-resource/how-to-stop-windows-10-from-automatically-update.html) as best you can.